# How to change content of character array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, character

```
char a[]="abcd";
a[]="zxc";
printf("%s",a);
```

it gives me the error saying  "error: expected expression before ']' token ". How do I change the value of my character array then?

Comment: you can't assign to an array, that's a limitation of C. You can use for example `strcpy()` to write into a (`char`) array.

Comment: `a = "zxc";` But you're just changing the pointer where `a` points to not the array itself as it is an array of constant characters.

Comment: @AndreKampling you still can't assign to an array, no matter which syntax you try ...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Thanks right. He must use `const char* a = "abcd";`. But as the others said, use `strcpy` for example.

Comment: @Andre Kampling - you cant change it as `a` is not the pointer  which can be changed as it has no representation in the storage - only data in the table have.

Answer (score 4):

You cant assign string to array.

You must do it with `strcpy()` or manually character by character using a loop:

```
strcpy(a, "zxc");
```

or

```
strncpy(a, "zxc", 4);   // Cause error's, be careful with that function.
```

or

```
a[0] = 'z';
```

Comment: I would not recommend `strncpy` to the beginners

Comment: That's true, i wrote it just for completention.

Comment: It's pointless in this toy example, but makes for a more complete answer.

Comment: `strncpy` is error prone and dangerous - extreme care is needed when used

Comment: Ok ill note it in A.

Comment: C is error prone and dangerous .... oh, my.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Haha.

Comment: @Felix Palmen  people are error prone. strncpy IMO is a disaster as functions with the `str` at the begging are expected produce the valid strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways - the most important two:

you can change a particular element in the array

```
 a[2] = '3';
```

or copy a new string

```
 strcpy(a, "wer");
```

but you need to remember that your array has only 5 elements including the trailing zero

Comment: Please don't post incomplete answers as "placeholders".

Comment: He wouldn't write it if he havent tho `o.O`.

Comment: It's pretty pointless asking me. You don't think I comment this just for fun, do you? Please don't do this and play fair.